# I don't get a response from the button

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to test the Button but for some reason, it doesn't work. The Bot sends a Message with the Button but I don't get anything in the console. Can anyone say me why?

```py
@commands.command()
async def butn(self, ctx):
await ctx.send("Test", components=[
    Button(
        style = 1,
        label = "Button",
        emoji = ""
    )
])

def check(res):
    return True

while True:
    res = await self.client.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
    print(res)
```

These are my Imports:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord_components import Button
```

Comment: This has to do with the while True: not exiting as well as not properly using the button functions from discord.ui

Answer (score -3):

Infinite loops are not recommended and thats not the correct way to have a button callback.

First, you shuld define your button in a variable like this:

```
button = Button(style = 1, label = "Button", emoji = "")
```

Then, you should define a callback function like this:

```
async def button_callback(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Click!")
```

And set the callback to the button like this:

```
button.callback = button_callback
```

Finally, send the message

```
await ctx.send("Test", components=[button])
```

For more documentation on the interaction object in the callback visit [this link](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction)

Comment: Downvoted because this question does not ask about how to make buttons in **pycord**, but rather how to make buttons in **discord.py + discord-components**. Infinite loops are what is recommended in that library and button callbacks do not exist.

Comment: Link needs to be fixed to refer to the new documentation link